# The type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' exists in both

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, 2016, reporting-services, on-premise-data-gateway

I have one SSRS Report using SOAP in sharepoint.In my viaual studio code it is showing one error.

Compilation Error:The type.Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials.exists.in both c:\Windows\assembly\GAC-MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\12.0.0.0-89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.Reportviewer.WebForms.DLL and c:\Windows\assembly\GAC-MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\10.0.0.0-b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll"

I tried to add qualifyAssembly node in web.config.But it is not working.Visual studio version is 2015.I am using sharepoint 2016 onpremise.
How to solve it?